# Regex: select line by prefix and erase/replace with Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I've a text file as follow:

```
FRAME 589
0 99 267 151 343
15 717 218 759 318
20 81 312 118 367
FRAME 590
0 99 267 150 343
15 725 218 765 317
20 80 311 115 367
FRAME 591
0 112 267 144 343
15 729 218 769 316
20 79 311 115 367
21 110 272 111 290
```

Using `Sublime Text`, I would like to:

1. erase lines which don't start with `15` (this value maps an ID).
2. replace ID `15` with `1` (without edit other values after the first whitespace).

How can I perform these operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> erase lines which don't start with 15 (this value maps an ID)

You can match all the lines not starting with `15` using the following regex:

```
^(?!15|FRAME).*(?:\r?\n|\r|$)
```

And then use the empty string `""` as the replacement string to remove those lines.

> replace ID 15 with 1 (without edit other values after the first whitespace).

Use the following regex to match 15 at the start of the line:

```
^15
```

now use a replacement string of simply `1`, this will replace all `15` at the start of each line with `1`.

Comment: With `^(?!15).*(?:\r?\n|\r|$)` I select also strings that start with `FRAME`. I would like to exclude them.

Comment: @vdenotaris I have edited my answer a little bit, please check edit. You just need to modify the regex a bit `^(?!15|FRAME).*(?:\r?\n|\r|$)`.